# Disable saved password menu in text input

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

In a simple `text` `input`, saved password menu pops up. I simple do not want this menu to pop up. Is there a way to disable this?

*P.S. I'm still kinda new to web-development in general and don't exactly know how to ask the right questions.*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `autoComplete` attribute of input tag.

For further detail you can read following article from MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion